# @include a view with controller functionality - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a profile page for my web application. Within this view `profile.blade.php` I would like to include the view `progress/index.blade.php`. I have the following structure:

> profile.blade.php

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
            <h1 class="panel-title pull-left">{{ $user->name }} Progress</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @include('client.progress.index')
        </div>
</div>
```

> web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'client'], 'prefix' => 'client', 'as' => 'client.'], function () {
    Route::get('home', 'Client\HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('profile', 'Client\UserController@profile')->name('profile');
    Route::get('progress', 'Client\UserController@progress')->name('progress.index');
});
```

> UserController@progress

```
public function progress(){

        $auth = Auth::user();
        $progressPictures = Picture::select('*')
            ->where('user_id', $auth->id)
            ->get();

        return view('client.progress.index', ['progressPictures' => $progressPictures]);
    }
```

> client.progress.index

```
<p>Progress pictures</p>

@foreach($progressPictures as $progressPicture)
    <img src="/storage/uploads/progress/{{ $progressPicture }}" style="width:150px; height:150px; float:left; border-radius:50%; margin-right:25px;">
@endforeach
```

When I remove the php part from the `index.blade.php`, the site works. but when i add the `foreach` loop, `$progressPictures` is undefined. I am not calling the `UserController@progress` in some way. Could some one help me with this?

Comment: Use `return view('client.progress.index')->with('progressPictures', $progressPictures);`

Comment: @HirenGohel still `Undefined variable: progressPictures`. The problem is that the controller is not being called.

Comment: Just `dd` in `UserController@progress`! Check is function call or not?

Comment: did that, nothing happens but the error still occurs.

Comment: Is `UserController ` in  `Client` directory??

Comment: Yes @HirenGohel

Comment: Define that route below middleware! Then check it please!

Comment: Is it working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally based on my observation, the variable is not making it to the views because you are routing to another while the other view is handled by another controller.

One of the ways you can do that is either to have a trait where you can easily reuse the result of getting progressPictures or because you quickly need it, you might have to duplicate this code as well in the `profile` method in your `UserController` so that you can have the `progressPictures` also in profile page:

So you'll have:

```
public function profile()
{
    //codes before or after
    $auth = Auth::user();
    $progressPictures = Picture::select('*')
        ->where('user_id', $auth->id)
        ->get();
    //......
    return view('profile', compact('progressPictures'));
```

> Ps: unnecessary code repetition is not generally recommended, but I would do this first then clean up things after.

Comment: This solved my problem, but I decided to add the following JS: `$("#progress").load("{{ route('client.progress.index') }}");` and this worked too.

Answer (score 0):

Change this to

```
return view('client.progress.index', ['progressPictures' => $progressPictures]);
```

to this

```
return view('client.progress.index')-> with('progressPictures', $progressPictures);
```

Comment: @AnnaJeanine sorry that was  `return view('client.progress.index')-> with('progressPictures', $progressPictures);`

Comment: Thank you for the edit but it still doesn't work. The problem is that the controller is not being called. I changed the return view to another blade and I was still directed to the index.blade.php

Comment: Did that, still nothing.

Comment: @AnnaJeanine what error exactly you are getting in your console?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@include('client.progress.index')
```

to

```
@include('client.progress.index', ['progressPictures' => $progressPictures])
```